# How to compile and run assembly code in linux

Tags: linux, assembly, compilation

I am quite new to assembly and Linux as a whole. I found on gitHub a space invader program written in Assembly. But I tried compiling and running it, but have no clue how.

I first thought I could use gcc -o name name.s and that didnt work.

Like I said I am completely new to usuing linux and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to compile this and get it running.

Here's the link : https://github.com/timotei/Space-Invaders-Clone/blob/master/spacein.asm

Comment: That is a DOS program. Under linux, you'll need dosbox for it, and an assembler and linker.

Answer (score 2):

Under linux the standard assembler is `as`. If you want to use assembler sources inside a c or c++ environment you can give the compiler e.g. gcc a hint with `-xassembler` or `xassembler-with-cpp` if you want to use the C-preprocessor. Normally gcc also accepts assembler sources if the name of the file ends with standard file name like `*.s` or `*.S`.

There is already another question here which handles dos assembler:
[Taking an Assembly Course, Stuck in DOS!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224683/taking-an-assembly-course-stuck-in-dos)

And maybe you find some other discussions helpful:
https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-users/2007-November/028174.html

But I have no idea why someone wants to start with assembler on x86 at all if you are not a os programmer or kernel hacker. :-)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i'll look into everything you suggested. 

I'm learning x86-64 because I'm taking computer science in uni and this is what they're teaching